# useRedux On version 7

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm quite confused how is the functionality of the hook that appears on the react-redux 7.0.1? 
I even can't find an example, Anyone can provide a simple example of how to define or use the useRedux hook?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases

Comment: " lays the groundwork for us to design and ship a public useRedux()-type Hooks API in a later 7.x release." Ok, it is just a matter of time, thanks for the link